# How to order by ACF select label instead of value?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Custom query, trying to sort posts by the state selected on an ACF select field, but using the label instead of the value.  Issue is right now I'm getting a few like Wisconsin (WI) coming before West Virginia (WV).  Thanks!

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'center',
  'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'state',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
);
```

Comment: I think you need to make the key similar to the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to order it by the state abbreviation it's probably best to create another field for the state abbreviation and then instead of ordering it by the full state name you can order by the abbreviation.